# Excel Application.OnTime

Tags: excel, vba, timer

I'm attempting to use VBAs `Application.OnTime` method to call a function every minute. The code that I have so far is as follows.

Defined globally:

```
Dim alertTime As Date
```

In one of the first methods that gets called:

```
alertTime = Now + TimeValue("00:00:10")
Application.OnTime alertTime, "myFunc"
```

In the `myFunc` method:

```
alertTime = Now + TimeValue("00:00:10")
Application.OnTime alertTime, "myFunc"
```

10 seconds after I've run the macro I get a warning dialog telling me `Error loading DLL`. I've not specified any other DLLs to be loaded in the `myFunc` method so that doesn't seem like it would be the problem. Is there an additional library I need to include to use `Application.OnTime`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shouldn't be, is myFunc in the same namespace though? If myFunc is not located in your namespace, or not created yet as a macro, by default Application.OnTime will look for a module named myFunc instead.

Comment: That sounds about right. Do you know of any good tutorials on using Namespaces or Modules? Nothing that I understand from C seems to translate very well.

Comment: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/codemods.htm is a decent guide to the excel modules, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb221399(v=office.12).aspx has some info directly related to your Application.OnTime, hope that provides some help to you!